# How can unauthorized movie purchases be made on my 1st generation Apple TV?

Tags: itunes, network, wifi, apple-id, appletv

In the last 6 months, two movies have shown up as purchased on my 1st Generation Apple TV, but neither I nor my wife have purchased them.

The first time this happened, I thought perhaps it had been done accidentally by my wife previewing a movie, then accidentally hitting the purchase button.

The second time this happened was last night when we were watching Monday Night Football. We were both sitting on the sofa and the AppleTV was NOT accessed by us.

Our ATV1 is a refurbished 160GB AppleTV purchased directly from Apple with the latest software version [3.0.2]. I run ethernet from a Netgear WNDR-3700 router to the AppleTV. Password has been changed from default on the router. I have disabled the guest networks (yes this router has two guest networks) on the router, but do run WiFi for the windows computers and three local Apple devices (2 phones, 1 iPad 2nd gen).

The first time this happened, I enabled two-step verification on my Apple ID. Strangely, I get the two-step challenge ONLY when I sign-in from my Chrome Browser on the AppleID site, [ https://appleid.apple.com/account/home ].

Can anyone tell me how unauthorized purchases could be made on my AppleTV without my knowledge?

Further, can anyone tell me how to lock down my network and 1st gen  AppleTV so that unauthorized purchases can't be made?

Comment: are those purchases on your account? did you pay for it?

Comment: Yes - I have been carefully checking the receipts from Apple since the first errant purchase. This was purchased on my main Apple ID - main meaning the one I use for about 95% of my purchases. I did pay for it with my credit card on file with Apple.

Comment: So why do you call it a unauthorized then. You did authorize it (or someone in you family did). Remove your credit card from apple.

Comment: Did that (removed credit card, after the 2nd purchase) - but was sitting in front of the ATV watching football when the purchase was made and I was NOT using the Apple TV (nor was anyone else).

Comment: Someone is hocked up to your ATV ? check its menu to find out who.

Comment: Thanks, Buscar for your continued help. Could you give me the path for checking the ATV menu. Immediately I think path:  "Settings/Computers/" which I have just checked again. The only link is to the iTunes Library on my networked laptop. Beside this path, where else should I check? While I was checking for intruders, I did set Parental Controls and enabled "Ask" on purchases of Movies and TV shows. One strange thing I noted was that for the first time ever, there were downloads waiting on the ATV. They seem to be podcasts, and without an Apple ID stored in the ATV, I can't download them.

Comment: I audited MAC (media access control hex IDs) on "attached devices" showing in my Netgear WNDR 3700 router. There were some (possible) unknown MACs showing, HOWEVER I am using a Netgear WN3000RP repeater which seems to change the MAC addresses of known devices when they are connected thru it, so I need to research if the repeater offsets the MAC IDs when devices connect thru it to the router. Did harden passwords for admin and logon to router and repeater using ethernet with radios disabled (router); unable to disable radios on repeater, but did administer via ethernet on the repeater.

Comment: UPDATE The WN3000RP repeater does indeed assign a virtual MAC address to connected devices. Those virtual MAC addresses then show up in the "attached devices" list on the WNDR3700 router (taken from the ARP table), along with their actual MACs (from when they were physically connected (not via repeater). So based on router logs & attached devices list, I have absolutely no evidence that someone else has been hooked up to my 1st gen ATV. Not to say it didn't occur - just no evidence considering the "virtual MACs." BTW - the 1st gen ATV is connected via Ethernet, disabling the ATV 2.4 radio.

Comment: Nice job, so no external source involved.

Comment: Except that two movies have been purchased using my credentials - and there are only two of us in the home. I assume that the ATV radio is actually disabled, and that no one can be in my router or repeater without being logged - could anyone be using my credentials to purchase movies which are set to auto download to ATV? I seem to remember choosing at some point to DL to ATV rather than devices because movies DL'd to ATV or iTunes laptop could be moved to other devices, but movies DL to devices had to stay on device. I can't find that setting now to alter it. Other suggestions? I thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a month old, but check your ir remote. My Fios remote is programmed to control my Apple TV. If the Apple TV is on, the remote may be triggering the purchases when you use the up, down and menu keys on it. Since you are watching another show through a different input, you won't even notice it until you get the bill. 
Reprogram the universal remote or tuck the Apple TV where the IR signal can't SE it.

Answer (score 1):

THANK YOU !! to everyone who tried to help. Never got an adequate answer to this question. I enabled two step verification with Apple and have had no errant charges since. Everyone has made the assumption that the purchase came from within my own home, but I have seen enough to know the Apple ID system and charges to Apple IDs are by no means perfect. My suggestion to all - enable two step verification on your Apple ID.